# How to receive Binary Message from Websocket Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, binary-data, arraybuffer

This is what i want

[image]

But this is what i get:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
    function App() {
  const greeting = 'Hello Function Component!';


  const socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.99.9/video');

  socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

  socket.onopen = (event) => console.log('Video connected');
 

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
         // Show the Binary messages 
         console.log('Testing:')
         console.log(event.data)
  }

  return <h1> {greeting} </h1>;
}

export default App;
```

[image]

The WebSocket connection is created successfullly, but i still not get the binary messages.  I thought when the connection established, i would get the messages.

where i did wrong